# Codeigniter Can not send email there are some error when hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail, hosting

My project is work fine in localhost of my pc, but hosted it on the server there are some errors.

This is my function in codeigniter:

```
 function sendMail_confirm_register(){

  $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => 'myemail@gmail.com', 
      'smtp_pass' => 'mypassword',
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
  );


  $this->load->library('email', $config);
  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
  $this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com','mydomain.com');
  $this->email->to('someone@gmail.com');
  $this->email->subject('Complete your registration!');
  $this->email->message('Test Message');
    if($this->email->send())
    {
       echo "The email has been sent!";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Cannot send email!";
    }


}
```

This is error as below:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /base/data/home/apps/s~postleng/2.380394098175674288/ctm-hotel-system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 442
An Error Was Encountered

The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:

from:

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:

to:

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: DATA

data:

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Thu, 27 Nov 2014 03:57:16 -0500 From: "mydomain.com" Return-Path: To: login@gmail.com Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Complete_your_registration!?= Reply-To: "myemail@gmail.com" X-Sender: myemail@gmail.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID: <5476e76cb1a8a@gmail.com> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5476e76cb1ae4" This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application may not support this format. --B_ALT_5476e76cb1ae4 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Please help  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a config file you still need to rename search in notepad++ for localhost. See htacces

Comment: @WeTheBrains I am sorry, I don't understand what you said. Please tell me detail about what you said.

Comment: My guess is that something is wrong with url configurations open notepad++ or any editor that lets you look for a word in a folder and choose your project folder and look for localhost or the name for host locally you may find a file wiTh important vars like constant url set to localhost/www.yourproject.com you need to change it to the new domain

Comment: @Darith: Is `fsockopen` enabled by your host?

Comment: @Iain I checked that fsockopen() is already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

May be try using **sendmail** protocol?